# How to alternatively prove: Any subgroup of any free Abelian group is free

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, alternative-proof, free-abelian-group

I am a bit hesitant to ask this question, but here goes. We call an Abelian group $\textit{free}$ if it has some basis $\{e_i\mid i\in I\neq\emptyset\}$. Unlike vector spaces, not all (non-trivial) free Abelian groups have a basis. However, the following result does hold.

> **Theorem**. Let $(F, +)$ be a free Abelian group. If $S$ is a subgroup of $F$, then $S$ is also free.

I have proven this result, and that $\operatorname{rank}(S)\leq \operatorname{rank}(F)$, on the assumption that $F$ has a finite basis.

In the more general case, the proofs of which I am aware use transfinite induction, Zorn's lemma, and some isomorphism theorems. Unfortunately, I have extremely limited experience with Zorn's lemma, and no exposure to transfinite induction and the classic group isomorphism theorems. This lack of knowledge is the motivation for this question.

***Question***: Is there a way to give a more "elementary" proof of the above theorem?

Probably some form of Zorn's lemma (or a bit weaker) is required. By "elementary", I mean that perhaps one can do without the transfinite induction and isomorphism theorems. Maybe some form of a proof by contradiction which utilises the finite version of the theorem to arrive at the contradiction. Or even try to construct the basis of $S$ by decomposing $S$ somehow into finite subgroups.

Any hope of success?

Comment: It turns out that this fact has a beautiful relationship with [topology of graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen%E2%80%93Schreier_theorem). But Zorn's lemma is required.

Comment: Clearly the axiom of choice has to come up at some point.

Comment: @dsw That's interesting. I will look into it. @ Captainlama too: I'm not entirely convinced that the entirety of AoC is required, but I do agree that AoC (equiv. Zorn's lemma) or something a bit weaker is indeed required. Thank you for confirming. However, what about doing a proof *with* Zorn's lemma *but without* transfinite induction and the classic isomorphism theorems?

Comment: @dsw: You are confusing free groups (which are indeed related to graphs) and free abelian groups, where the standard proofs do not use graphs (I do not think, there are any graph-theoretic proofs of the subgroup theorem for free abelian groups).

Comment: @MoisheKohan : I think one may deduce the result for free abelian groups from the one for free groups (take a subgroup, pull it back to the free group, do your proof there, and proof via Hurewicz that your subgroup is the abelianization of the pullback to the free group - that last step is dubious since I didn't write it down but it might work)

Comment: @Max: It will not work since the abelianization map is not injective; hence, for the abelianization map $c: F\to A$, $(c^{-1}(B))^{ab}$ is not isomorphic to $B$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan : ah you're right, it was obvious in fact ! (take $B= 0$, then $c^{-1}(B) = [F,F]$ is a free group on more than $0$ generators ) - thanks

Comment: This old Wikipedia's proof is taken straight from Lang's book:  https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Free_abelian_group&oldid=317358888#Subgroup_closure

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you for that link, very useful. With that and some three-four other textbooks I managed to put together a reasonable proof without transfinite induction, and without the classic isomorphism theorems. Maybe I'll post it here sometime. Thanks again!